# How do I access my local apache server from Windows running in Parallels hosted on MacOS X?

Tags: windows-7, macos, apache-http-server, parallels

I'm running Windows 7 from within Parallels running on MacOS X Lion. I've also setup a local apache server; I can access this server from MacOS X via any browser. I've configured this using a combination of `/etc/hosts` and configuring the `vhosts` file: typing in `http://epwbst` into my browser brings me to the expected website on the MacOS X side. Doing this on the Windows side doesn't do the right thing. I **am** able to access any other web resource.

I suspect that I need to reconfigure the DNS on the Windows side to look to the MacOS X side first. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest answer is to add an entry for epwbst, with your Mac's IP address, to the Windows hosts file in the same way you did for the Mac.

Windows stores the hosts file in a different location:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

You'll need to add the actual IP address of your Mac in there (if you're using Bridged networking), check how you've configured networking in Parallels.

If you're using DHCP to set your Mac's IP address, it's a good idea to reserve a fixed address in your router (if possible).

Comment: Thanks! This works. Do you have a suggestion for configuring either Parallels or Windows because I constantly change network locations (thus my Mac's IP address is always changing). As a tip to others, edit `hosts` using administrative privileges (either on Windows or on MacOS X). I used Notepad with admin privileges on (right-click and select use as admin).